# run web application in netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, netbeans

I am using netbeans and apache tomcat in order to run web application. I keep getting this error:

```
In-place deployment at C:\WorkingDirectory\Projects\GreenWheelsProject\GreenWheels-Java\green-wheels-project\share-wheels\target\share-wheels
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FDOCUME%7E1%2F0DD4%7E1%2FLOCALS%7E1%2FTemp%2Fcontext600644043101946969.xml&path=/
FAIL - Deployed application at context path / but context failed to start
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:179)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:131)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:211)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

The server log is:

```
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
```

and the output of the sever is:

```
אפר 14, 2012 3:54:59 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase stop
INFO: The stop() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] after stop() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
אפר 14, 2012 3:54:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context []
אפר 14, 2012 3:54:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor ROOT.xml from C:\Documents and Settings\נאור\.netbeans\7.1.1\apache-tomcat-7.0.22.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost
אפר 14, 2012 3:54:59 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\WorkingDirectory\Projects\GreenWheelsProject\GreenWheels-Java\green-wheels-project\share-wheels\target\share-wheels\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
אפר 14, 2012 3:55:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

This is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.success</groupId>
  <artifactId>share-wheels</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>share-wheels Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>share-wheels</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

What is wrong here??..

***EDIT:***
This problem accures when I add the following to thw pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Why is this? I need this dependency for HttpServletRequest. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try removing the servlet and JSTL classes from the WAR you are deploying.

Comment: Which servlet?.. Where is it (it is not in the pom)? this is a new project. How to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same deployment failure that Naor. My Tomcat webapps folder doesn't have the manager module (I removed!) that comes with the default Tomcat dist. So, when NetBeans tries to deploy  on the web container (Tomcat) then it fails, 'cause there is no manager module. Restoring the manager module resolves the error message.

Comment: I have had the same problem and you can easily fix it by making sure your  manager module within Tomcat is proper. Even if the manager module exists, make sure it has all the files of a default manager module.

Answer (score 12):

Use `<scope>provided</scope>` to indicate that you need the artifact to compile, but not to have it in your war.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why I don't need it in the war?

Comment: Because the relevant parts of this jar (servlet etc.) are already included in your server.

Comment: So what? :) What happens when I add it again? Why does it break?

Comment: The servlet specification allows the container to reject illegal definitions, like classes belonging to the `java....` namespace.  These API's do.

Answer (score -1):

Right Click..Do Clean And build!!!
I have faced this issue while developing Spring web MVC application in netbeans..Generally clean and build worked